# Search by date using command line

Tags: search, date, find, cmd, dir

Is there any way to search for files in a directory based on date? I want to find all files with created date greater than a specific date, is it possible to do it with `dir` command?

Comment: `dir /OD` will sort by date, at least

Comment: dir cannot, but the Unix find command *can*. [Dos port available here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/)

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/326025/3588 at SuperUser is an elegant solution using `xcopy` without actually copying

Comment: The xcopy solution applies to modified and not created date.

Comment: Time to change the accepted answer.

Comment: @noumenon, What's wrong with the accepted answer?  Seems like the best one to me.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @SixSigmaGuy #1: It's 41 to 6 that the `forfiles` answer is better, but in 2017 the 6 vote answer would appear first and waste our time. `forfiles` is the tool built for the job, with no ugly %%~ parsing.

Comment: @Noumenon Thank you!  That's what I'll use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dir` by itself can not filter by date, but you can parse the output of `dir` using `for` command. If in your country `dir` prints the date in YMD format, then you only need to compare it with given date. If the order of date parts is different, then you have to use another `for` command to parse the date and change it to YMD. This will display a list of files modified after 5th Februrary.

```
@Echo Off

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,4 skip=5" %%A in (`dir /-c`) do (
  if %%A GTR 2012-02-05 echo %%A %%B
)
```

`if` does standard string comparison, so at the end you can get additional line if summary line passes the comparison. To avoid it, you can use `if %%A GTR 2012-02-05 if exist %%B echo %%A %%B`

EDIT:
There is even better approach which avoids parsing of `dir` output and also allows searching by time, not only by date:

```
@Echo Off

for /r %%A in (*) do (
  if "%%~tA" GTR "2012-02-05 00:00" echo %%~tA %%A
)
```

Comment: thanks you that's what i need, can i use the hour:minutes with comparison. Finally is there helpful books to learn shell scripting.

Comment: To use minutes in comparison, do the following changes: `tokens=1,2,4` and then `if "%%A %%B" GTR "2012-02-05 11:23" echo %%A %%B %%C`
To learn, you can start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file and then continue with three first external links.

Answer (score 42):

Just discovered the `forfiles` command.

```
forfiles /s /m *.log /d -7 /c "cmd /c echo @path"
```

Will list all the log files modified more than seven days old, in all subdirectories, though it does not appear to look at the create date. It does support specifying a specific date.

See `forfiles /?` for more info.

Comment: Super-useful! (when no PowerShell available) NOTE: If you want files modified after a date you need `+` instead of `-` for the `/d` parameter, so something like `+02/05/2012` instead of `-7`. Also to show the date and time output for each file you could use `cmd /c echo @fdate @ftime @path`

Comment: Caveat: Woe betide ye who want to use UNC paths with this. Or in many other places in Windows...

Comment: `FORFILES /D` only works with modified dates. To solve UNC issues just use `MKLINK /D`.

Comment: For anyone expecting `/d +7` to show you files modified fewer than seven days ago, nope. It will shows you [files modified seven days from now](https://www.windows-commandline.com/find-files-based-on-modified-time/). You have to use a date, like `+02/05/2012`.

Answer (score 10):

an easier way for me is something like

```
dir /s *.xlsx | find "07/14/2016"
```

Comment: How to add also time ?

Answer (score 3):

Well you cant as far as i know, but this sort of think will work, but still really useless unless you have a short date range ;)

```
for /R %a in (01 02 03 04 05) do dir | find "02/%a/2012"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do with PowerShell. I know that your question was about cmd, but PS is included in windows 7 and later. It can also be installed on XP and Vista.

Use the `Get-ChildItem` command (aliased as `dir`) to get all files. Pipe the output to the `Where-Object` command (aliased as `?`) to return files where the date is greater then (`-gt`) a specific date.

For Powershell 2.0 (default on Windows 7), you must use a scriptblock:

```
dir -file | ? {$_.LastWriteTimeUtc -gt ([datetime]"2013-05-01")}
```

For Powershell 3.0 (default on Windows 8) and up you can use this simpler syntax instead:

```
dir -file | ? LastWriteTimeUtc -gt ([datetime]"2013-05-01")
```

The `dir -file` command returns a collection of `System.IO.FileInfo` objects. This file object has many properties that you can use for complex filtering (file size, creation date, etc.). See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) for documentation.

Comment: I tried:  dir . *.svg | ? LastWriteTimeUtc -gt ([datetime]"2013-05-01") but received "Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "LastWriteTimeUtc" value of type "System.String
" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".

Comment: The syntax I used works for PS 3.0 and up I believe. If you have PS 1.0 or 2.0, you must use a scriptblock like so: `| ? {$_.LastWriteTimeUtc -gt ([datetime]"2013-05-01")}`

Comment: dir -file throws "A parameter cannot be found" on 2.0

Comment: Can someone please explain why this command finds all files modified on the date but disregards the time?

    dir -s -file | ? LastWriteTimeUtc -gt ([datetime]"2015-03-07 16:00:00")

That is, it finds all file modified after 2015-03-07 00:00:00, which is NOT what I want.  I want all files modified after 4pm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JoelFinkel it works fine for me. BTW you're filtering using UTC time so that might explain the difference.

Comment: i believe for local time, you want `LastWriteTime`. Seems to work for me.