# CMD : how to list files updated after a specified date in a directory using commands

Tags: command-line, cmd, command

i want to list files that i updated today or after any particular date .
I have tried using `timeField` but am not able to get the expected results. How can i use DIR with other parameters to list down files that were updated after a specified date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search by date using command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234207/search-by-date-using-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

make an empty dummy directory, then use xcopy /l /y /d:m-d-y

```
md dummy
xcopy /L /y /d:m-d-y "yourdirectoryname" dummy >resultfilename.txt
rd dummy
```

should get you a list of filenames updated d-m-y or later into `resultfilename.txt`

Comment: `xcopy /L /I /d:4-30-2014 "d:\folder" "d:\folder\-" |find /v /i " files(s)"` <--- It's interesting Magoo that you can use the same folder in source and target, as long as the target has a non-existing folder name appended: I used `-` but you could use `aaa`or anything.  I think your code has the wrong date format - it's `m-d-y` in every locale AFAIK.